# Assigning value Windows Phone 7, logging operation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I'm working on WP7 + WCF Service app and I want to provide simple logging procedure. 
On main page I have one textbox for username, password box and log button.
Code on WP7 side is:

```
    namespace WP7App
    {
      public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
      {
         // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
         }
    private void Log(string username, string passwd)
    {
        Service1Client proxy = new Service1Client();
        proxy.LogInCompleted += new
        EventHandler<LogInCompletedEventArgs>(proxy_LogInCompleted);
        proxy.LogInAsync(username, passwd);
    }

    public void proxy_LogInCompleted(object sender, LogInCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool prompt = e.Result; //#PROBLEM LINE(?)
    }
    public void LogInButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (LoginBox.Text == null) { MessageBox.Show("Enter your login"); }
        if (PasswdBox.Password == null) { MessageBox.Show("Enter your password"); }
        string login = LoginBox.Text;
        string passwd = PasswdBox.Password;
        Log(login, passwd);     

    }

    }
   }
```

My problem is that in #PROBLEM LINE(?) bool prompt isn't getting e.Result value. I checked it in debugger and when e.Result have f.e true value but prompt stay always false.

Comment: Seems impossible :) Keep in mind that in Release mode C# compiler removes unused variables (like your promt).

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/571/debugm.png/
But you will agree with me that it should assign in debug mode.
Maybe it would be better to change public void Log to public bool, is it good idea?